# Using drawKeypoints in python opencv gives error: 'module' object has no attribute 'drawKeypoints'

Tags: python, opencv, sift

This is the code I am using:

```
import cv2
import cv
im=cv2.imread("box.png")
gr=cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
d=cv2.FeatureDetector_create("SIFT")
kp=d.detect(gr)
imm=cv2.drawKeypoints(im, kp)#[, outImage[, color[, flags]]])
# io.imshow(gr)
```

However I am getting the error that cv2 doesn't have drawKeypoints. I checked this myself:

```
d=dir(cv2)
if "drawKeypoints" in d: 
  print 'yes'
else: 
  print 'no'
```

and found that indeed it wasn't there. Is there any alternate functionality that is to be used, or is it some version related issue?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure about the question of version but I'm running OpenCV 2.4.11 and the cv2.drawKeypoints() is available after I do:

```
import cv2
```

If you still cannot get it to work you could use this alternative method from the common.py samples code:

```
def draw_keypoints(vis, keypoints, color = (0, 255, 255)):
    for kp in keypoints:
            x, y = kp.pt
            cv2.circle(vis, (int(x), int(y)), 2, color)
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

For python 3.5, I had to put the output image variable as a third parameter to the function.